# I am using ucwords function in php but it doesnt work for the strings like "T.m.traders" or "R.j.kumar".?

Tags: php

String that has to be converted

```
$bar = 'R.m.traders'; 

$bar = ucwords(strtolower($bar));
```

output should be

R.M.Traders

Comment: there always a dot(.) in your string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Try this Hope it helps

```
$bar = str_replace('.', ' ', $bar);
$bar = ucwords(strtolower($bar));
$bar = str_replace(' ', '.', trim($bar));
```

Comment: you can again Put . back like this ->'R.m.traders' by str_replace(' ', '.', $bar); This will again Change R M Traders into R.M.Traders

Answer (score 5):

You need to add delemeter `.` also called custom delimeter. You can check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php). Anyway try this:

```
<?php
$bar = 'R.m.traders'; 
$bar = ucwords(strtolower($bar), "."); //After dot(.) next letter will be in Capital.
echo $bar;
?>
```

Comment: @RuchishParikh! check [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) first, I am sure you did mistake.

Comment: @madmanmaddy No, now its updated, You can check the [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php). In my localhost with php version 5.5.30. it is working fine.

Comment: then @Sagar Singh answer is correct as its work with all version.

Comment: @RuchishParikh it added from php version `5.5.16`. its mentioned in changelog.

Answer (score 0):

`ucwords` should be doing the first letter caps. `R.m.traders` is consider single word. If you give `R m traders` means you will get `R M Traders`

Alter way:

```
$bar = 'R.m.traders'; 
  $bar_array = explode('.',$bar);
  if(!empty($bar_array)){
      $temp = array();
      foreach($bar_array as $bar_arr){
          $temp[] = ucwords(strtolower($bar_arr));
      }
      $bar_array = $temp;
  }
  $bar = implode('.',$bar_array);
  echo $bar;
```